# How to compile a DLL without using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll, unity-game-engine

That sounds a stupid question, but I'm really curious about how to compile a DLL without using Visual Studio since I'm using Unity3D OS X for now. Is there some way like "tool chain" can do the trick?

Any solution is appreciated except **Ask your friend/colleague to compile it for you** or **buy another computer/install windows/using remote control**.

Comment: Sure, there are other compilers available. Microsoft's is not your only option. I don't really understand what the question is; recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Comment: This falls under "install windows" but why not use something like VirtualBox or Parallels to create a Windows guest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a [cross tool chain of Mingw](http://mxe.cc/). However, be aware that you can not link C++ libraries between compilers, or often even compiler versions. Only DLLs with a C calling interface will work. (They can internally use C++ but must expose a C API.)

Or you could try running Visual Studio in Wine. VS2010 [has bronze support in Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20359), i.e. the compiler works.